# Google App engine - understanding how instances are started and what memory is needed (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memory

I'm trying to understand exactly how new instances are started by app engine for new requests. I've been working for some time with app engine, but I don't know anymore where I don't know the docs (haven't done my "homework") and where there is a bug/scheduler issue.

I have just tried to create a new web app project (Java - Eclipse) containing just the "Hello world" servlet. Then I deployed it to my cloud console app on a test version to see how much memory is needed at first load.

There are 2 findings that i don't understand:

1. After i call the test servlet, the instance has already 120Mb consumption. Why is so much memory needed? Is this the memory of java jvm of the instance, or all of the container?
2. Each time i call the servlet a new instance is started. I called (subsequently, not in parallel) it 10 times and I had 9 instances (1 request per each) and one had 2 requests handled. After that most requests were handled by the existing instances, but some of them, again spawned new instances. Why? (After each test (call to servlet) I waited to receive the response and a few seconds more before making new requests)

My appengine-web.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>[...]</application>
  <version>test-memory</version>

  <!--
    Allows App Engine to send multiple requests to one instance in parallel:
  -->
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

  <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>

    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>

    <precompilation-enabled>true</precompilation-enabled>

    <instance-class>F1</instance-class>
      <automatic-scaling>
        <min-idle-instances>1</min-idle-instances>
        <max-idle-instances>2</max-idle-instances>
        <min-pending-latency>350ms</min-pending-latency>
        <max-pending-latency>automatic</max-pending-latency>

      </automatic-scaling>



</appengine-web-app>
```

Servlet code:

```
public class TestAppEngineMemServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");
    }
}
```

I tested with Java 1.9.42 SDK and used Java 8 for local dev with Java compiler compliance level 7 (if it matters), standard environment with F1 or F2 instance classes.

Please advise, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanic for spawning new instances is actually really simple. You have pending latency, which is the time a request is in the queue before it is handled by an available instance.

If pending latency goes beyond a threshold you specify a new instance will be spun up.

Now what should be interesting for you is the warmup requests which happens every time a new instance is spun up and therefor takes a little while longer.

Let's assume your test was like this

```
t+0s: request #1 (causes warmup since there is no instance yet)
t+1s: request #2 (causes warmup since the first instance is not there yet)
t+2s: ... you get where this is going ...
t+8s: the first instance is now ready to serve and requests are being processed
t+9s: the second instance is now ready to serve
t+xs: request #x (does not cause warmup requests because there are enough instances)
t+xs: instances slowly spin down because there isn't enough traffic to justify its existence
```

What you see here is that your request don't have to be in parallel to cause seemingly idiotic behaviour.

**As for memory (which really should be a separate question):**
what you see is the memory used by the container / vm. This is approximately the memory of your Java VM + probably a bit of boilerplate for the docker image's environment that's housing it. Java allocates memory for runtime so it's always going to be relatively high when compared with, let's say C/C++ (you can specify this locally with the -Xms/-Xmx parameters)

So the memory is not necessary needed but allocated for the JVM to use. The amount of memory may increase over time but when memory is freed in the JVM it isn't necessarily returned to the system at once.

Comment: For point 2. I should add that I always waited for the response before calling the servlet again, so every time i made a new request for "Hello world" servlet, a bunch of instances were already serving (each of them finished responding)... but still, new instances were started. (I have edited my post)

Comment: That is indeed a noteworthy addition. It's also something that shouldn't happen, especially with min_pending_latency set that high.

Comment: For point 1. - From those 120Mb, will it ever go down to less memory?  I mean if I have F1 instances, does it mean that I  will only have 8Mb of free memory for my instances?

Comment: And another interesting fact: after the 20-30 tests I made for that version (the one with only a "hello world" servlet that spawned 12 instances) I the instances "untouched" (so no interaction). After 1 hour, 4 of them were still up and the next request was handled by one of the existing instances. After a minute, i made another call, and another instance was starded. I know it sounds strange, but this behavior does not correspond to anything in the docs...

Comment: No you have more memory that that. A good portion of those 120Mb is allocated as heap space for your JVM. This is memory that you can use and are using. If the JVM would give away some of that memory it could reallocate it from the system, but that would be just useless effort, so the JVM just keeps the memory while it's running.

Comment: I remember that Google had trouble properly spinning down instances for applications. It's possible that you're seeing ghost instances. You could try to address the instances directly `https://instance-dot-version-dot-service-dot-app-id.appspot.com` - see if they are actually alive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123162/discussion-between-andrei-f-and-konqi).